# is it possible to bypass the 'open save save as' dialog box in IE with a browser plugin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, plugins, wordperfect

I've been tasked with creating a browser plugin for IE to bypass the "Open Save Save As" dialog for opening word perfect documents generated by our .net web app.

I was told to investigate download managers and I've come across the following project:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSIEDownloadManager-8ab5d910/sourcecode?fileId=22583&pathId=1096685221

but as far as I can tell the IEDownloadManager Download method won't get called until after the user selects an option from that dialog and not before.

Any suggestions would be appreciated except those suggesting I use another browser. (the state won't let me)

Thanks.

Comment: It should be possible to register the file extension with IE (like most PDF readers do) and trigger your plugin to spin up a new process...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find an active x control, but as far as the website itself is concerned with IE, auto downloading and opening a file, this would be a pretty big security risk as someone could program it to auto open a malicious exe file.